# max sum skipping two consecutive integers

Tags: python, algorithm, sum, dynamic-programming, divide-and-conquer

I need to return max sum of array N skipping two consecutive values. 
For example, 
N = [10, 30, 50, 60, 5, 60].
Output: 175, skipping two first values [10,30] = 40.

I wrote this:

```
def maxSum(array):
  tempSum = sum(array)
  totalSum=0
  for i in range(len(array)):
    prevSum = tempSum - sum(array[i:i+2])
    if prevSum > totalSum:
      totalSum = prevSum
```

is there any way to resolve this by Greedy, DAC or dynamic prog.?

Comment: Your solution is O(N) (linear), so I doubt it can be improved upon; summing certainly requires full iteration anyway.

Comment: There's a bug in this implementation because `i` ranges up to `len(array)-1`, so the last "pair" you try is actually just one element.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is `O(n)` and *greedy*:

```
N = [10, 30, 50, 60, 5, 60]

total = sum(N)
result = max(total - sum(pair) for pair in  zip(N, N[1:]))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
175
```

Comment: `zip(*(2 * [iter(N)]))` gets you an iterator for pairwise stepping without slicing.

Comment: Also, this is *exactly the same solution* the OP posted, albeit using cleaner code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Does `zip(*(y := iter(N), y))` will do the same?

Comment: It does, but requires Python 3.8 or newer. :-)

Comment: @RaySteam No, that will pair like `(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)` instead of `(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6)`.

Comment: @kaya3 True, but I believe then that the solution provided by Martjin does the same

Comment: Yes. To iterate over all adjacent pairs without slicing, you can do `ahead = iter(N); next(ahead)` and then `zip(N, ahead)`.

Comment: @kaya3 I Agree.